# Smartgwt Load Test with BrowserMob

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, load-testing

As told in Smartgwt - AutomatedTesting documentation, we have been trying to use BrowserMob for load testing but the script that selenium ide created can not pass the validaton of the BrowserMob. I think it is related with scLocators because the error shows the line of first scLocator. How can BrowserMob be use with Smartgwt - Selenium Scripts? Can load testing be done in any other way / tool ? Thank you.

--Ubuntu 10.10
--Smartgwt 3.1d
--Gwt 2.4